# Can I see an actual model of my Intel GPU in my distro's About screen?

Tags: hardware, elementary-os, intel, gpu, intel-graphics

When I go to the "About" window of elementaryOS I see this:

[image]

Why doesn't it display the actual consumer-facing name of the GPU (Intel® Iris® Plus Graphics 640)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when your system’s PCI id database doesn’t have a description for your graphics device. The current upstream database does know about the Iris Plus Graphics 640, so updating the database should fix things:

```
sudo update-pciids
```

Comment: Honestly I did not expect such an easy solution. Cool, thanks! May I know, how did you know about that?

Comment: I don’t know how I know about this — I know that PCI information comes from the PCI id database, and that displaying an id (5926) instead of a name is usually caused by missing information there. So I checked the current version, saw that it has a match that was added not long ago, and reckoned that updating the database would fix things for you...